# Excel OpenText() from F# Compile and Run-Time Error

Tags: f#, excel-2010

I am using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in F# to automate the opening and conversion of a CSV file to Excel workbook for end-users.

When specifying the field info parameter for the OpenText() call in F# using integers, I get a run-time complaint about using integers--they're not XlColumnDataTypes.

```
let fieldInfo = [| [|1;2|] ; [|2;2|] ; [|3;1|] ; [|4;1|] ; [|5;1|] ; [|6;1|] ; [|7;1|] ; [|8;1|] |]
let xl = ApplicationClass()
xl.Workbooks.OpenText(fileName, StartRow=1, DataType=XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
                      TextQualifier=XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone, Comma=true,
                      FieldInfo=fieldInfo)
let wb = xl.Workbooks.Item(1)
```

**Error**: SafeArrayTypeMismatchException was unhandled: Specified array was not of the expected type.

But when I specify XlColumnDataTypes, I get compile-time complaints that I'm not using integers.

```
let fieldInfo = [| [|1;XlColumnDataType.xlTextFormat|];
                   [|2;XlColumnDataType.xlTextFormat|];
                   [|3;XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat|];
                   [|4;XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat|];
                   [|5;XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat|];
                   [|6;XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat|];
                   [|7;XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat|];
                   [|8;XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat|] |]
```

**Error**: This expression was expected to have type     int     but here has type     XlColumnDataType.

Has anyone else ever seen this? Does anyone know a way around this?

Thanks!

Comment: I've edited my original answer to address your specific problem with field information parameter. Enjoy!

Comment: Could you possibly post some code?  Maybe you could possibly share the exact error message--the exact "run-time complaint about using integers"? That is, assuming that @GeneBelitski hasn't already answered your question.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about the lack of code and error messages. I've added both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Field information argument of `OpenText()` for CSV should be a two-dimensional array of `System.Object` elements, i.e. `obj[,]`, like `fieldInfo`value in the snippet below ([Excel interop details are available here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.opentext)):

```
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    let fieldInfo: obj[,] = Array2D.zeroCreate 2 2
    fieldInfo.[0,0] <- box 1;
    fieldInfo.[0,1] <- box XlColumnDataType.xlTextFormat;
    fieldInfo.[1,0] <- box 2;
    fieldInfo.[1,1] <- box XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat;
    let app = new ApplicationClass(Visible=true)
    app.Workbooks.OpenText(@"C:\test.txt", StartRow=1,
        DataType=XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited,
        TextQualifier=XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone,
        Comma=true, FieldInfo=fieldInfo)
    0
```

Now, if you put into `c:\test.txt` file something like `abc,123` it will be parsed into the workbook without problems.

*EDIT:* `FieldInfo` can be initialized in more succinct way; instead of 5 code lines above the following array expression will do the same:

```
let fieldInfo: obj[] = [|[|1; int XlColumnDataType.xlTextFormat|];
                         [|2; int XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat|]|]
```

Original run-time exception you've encountered has nothing to do with type of array elements as `XlColumnDataType` is just an enumeration, so for Excel they are integers. What Excel does not like is that you feed it a F# jugged array of type `int[][]`. If you just force **`fieldInfo`** type in your original snippet from F#-inferred **`int[][]`** to explicit **`obj[]`** this small change will make it work.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much. Not only did I have to box the values, but I also had to use a mutable array instead of an array expression. I don't understand why I had to do that; but at least my code works now. Thank you so much!

Comment: @JeffManer: You are very welcome (c: In fact, as this is VB-like interop the same can be achieved with array expression of integers and compiler will do boxing for you.
But you should cast `XlColumnDataType` to `int` as F# array should have members of the same type. I've edited my code to a more succinct.